# VPN with RSA SecurID

Tags: networking, vpn

**Issue**, I tried setup and connect to VPN with SecurID, but nothing happened.

[image]

I have this information about VPN.

```
authentication method: SecurID; SecurID authentication: PinPad
```

**Question**, is possible connect to this VPN from linux ubuntu? Do I need some extra configuration file? Is my configuration and vpn configured correctly? Could I use configuration file from MAC (`*.sdtid`) on linux for VPN connect (or this file is only for generating token)? What kind of VPN should I use?

And about token, I am getting it from app on Android (SecurID), but I tried `stoken` for Ubuntu, but this app generate 8 digits, but I Android app generate only 6 digits (it works). Where could be the problem?

Just note, that on Win or MAC is this application needed for connection to VPN. Is this Cisco AnyConnect as the VPN client? Can I use `network-manager-openvpn-gnome`?

[image]

Comment: On your screenshot you didn't provide any certificate. It couldn't work.
In most cases, the VPN work on all OS (OSX,Linux, Win, android, iOS), so the problem is not here. But maybe you should look at this : [https://superuser.com/questions/353547/can-i-use-an-rsa-securid-software-token-on-ubuntu-linux](https://superuser.com/questions/353547/can-i-use-an-rsa-securid-software-token-on-ubuntu-linux)
What file have you to connect to this VPN ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for Ubuntu.

1. Update and install necessary packages.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5:i386 libx11-6:i386 libpam0g:i386 -y
```

2. Get snx_install.sh file and install.

```
wget https://starkers.keybase.pub/snx_install_linux30.sh?dl=1 -O snx_install.sh
chmod a+rx snx_install.sh
sudo ./snx_install.sh
sudo ldd /usr/bin/snx
```

3.1. Run `snx` directly.

```
snx -s CheckpointURLFQDN -u USER
# signature saved to /etc/snx/USER.db
```

3.2. Or better, make configuration file in your `HOME` folder.

```
echo "server example.com
username user@example.com
reauth yes
" > ~/.snxrc
```

4.1. Then you can simple connect.

```
snx
```

4.2. And disconnect.

```
snx -d
```

5. Download snx app for android.

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rsa.securidapp
```

6. Ask the provider to sent you link via email. You can open on cellphone via SecureID.

Enjoy!